# Mobile Scrolling Bug

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I was developing a small one page next app when I discovered a "bug".
And I don't know how to fix it. [Mobile Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwmv3.jpg)

Link to the site: [Preview](https://xreem-desktop-app-biiiiy16q-xreem.vercel.app/)

Current behaviour:
Screen Glitches when scrolling on mobile.

Expected behaviour:
No white space on the bottom part

Steps to reproduce:

1. Scroll up until the Chrome header hides
2. The white space appears on the bottom while the header fades away

For some reason it glitches when scrolling.
I tried setting the body to `calc(100vh + 60px)` (Header height)

But this doesn't fix the behavior.

Short snippet:

```
<main>
  <section className={'wrapper'}/>
  <section className={'wrapper'}/>
  <section className={'wrapper'}/>
  <section className={'wrapper'}/>
<main>
```

the corresponding CSS:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: calc(100vh + 60px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

The white space in the picture linked above fixes itself after the scroll.
It matches the height of the Chrome header
It seems that the Chromeheader does not affect the `height: 100vh`
Is my CSS wrong or is it a Bug?

I use a OnePlus 6
OxygenOS 11.1.2.2
Chrome: 98.0.4758.87

Answer (score 0):

If the header is fixed, you don't need make the calc, Even if the header if not fixed, you have to subtract and not add.

try it:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Same person, but work Account: U don't understand. My Header is fine. The Chrome Adressbar is buggy